# Removing certain rows in Pandas Dataframe by string format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column called Zip Code. The column is an object data type and some rows are not in proper zip code format. I would like to remove rows that do not contain ##### format zipcode.

```
    Subscriber Type     Zip Code
0   Subscriber         94040
1   Customer           11231
2   Customer           11231
3   Customer           32
4   Customer           nil
```

What would be an easy way to do so?
Is there a way to compare format and the records something like this? df.drop(df['Zip Code'] != #####)

Comment: why don't you do `df=df[df['Zip Code']!=#####)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
In [23]: df = df[df['Zip Code'].str.contains(r'^\d{5}$')]

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
  Subscriber Type Zip Code
0      Subscriber    94040
1        Customer    11231
2        Customer    11231
```

Explanation:

```
In [22]: df['Zip Code'].str.contains(r'^\d{5}$')
Out[22]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Zip Code, dtype: bool
```

PS thanks to [@Alberto Garcia-Raboso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596519/removing-certain-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-by-string-format/38596575?noredirect=1#comment64581535_38596575) for the refined RegEx!

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: `r'\d{5}'` gives false positives (for example: `11231asdf`, `asdf11231`, `as11231df`). You want a more stringent regex: `r'^\d{5}$'`

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, thank you! I've updated my answer